# ionic 4 ionViewWillEnter not call

Tags: ionic5

we used `local storage`  to store data when user login to app
when update storage for name not change in all pages
if close app and open it again it's work
when used `ionViewWillEnter` when user back to main page  and change `local storage` for name but not called

```
  ionViewWillEnter(){
    this.name  = localStorage.getItem('name')
    this.avatar  = localStorage.getItem('avatar')
  }
```

when user update profile

```
this.service.SendDataFile("users/edite",data).subscribe((res) => {
  localStorage.setItem('phone',this.phone)
  localStorage.setItem('name',this.name)
  this.service.ShowToast(res['msg'])
  this.navCtrl.navigateForward('tabs/tab3')

});
```

Answer (score 0):

try using async await

```
async ionViewWillEnter(){
    this.name  = await localStorage.getItem('name')
    this.avatar  = await localStorage.getItem('avatar')
}
```

Comment: `localstorage` calls are synchronous, so this shouldn't make any difference

Comment: when change localstorage  it's change in same page , but not changed in all pages !